# maximal ideal not containing some expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Does there exists a domain $R$ with fraction field $K$, and $x \in K \setminus R$, such that for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \leq R[x]$, there exists $a \in R$ such that $x-a \in \mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Why did you delete so much of the content of your question?

Comment: I first asked some question not sufficiently clearly, and Crostul answered to a different question. Then I upgraded the question, but no one answered to it, and after a while, I reasked the question in another thread. This was marked as duplicate, so I saw no other solution but to change the question here in order it correspond to the answer of Crostul - probably not a good practice I admit. The original question is now asked in another thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154173/ring-with-maximal-ideal-not-containing-a-specific-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to build a counterexample. I hope you are familiar with commutative algebra, and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Call $R = \mathbb{C}[T]$, $x = T^{-1}$. Then $R[x] = \mathbb{C}[T, T^{-1}] \cong \mathbb{C}[T, Y] / (TY-1)$.

Fix a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $\mathbb{C}[T, Y] / (TY-1)$. It has the form $$\mathfrak{m}=(T-\alpha, Y-\beta)/(TY-1)$$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $\alpha \beta =1$. Call $a = \alpha^{-2}T \in R$.

Then $x-a = Y - \alpha^{-2}T$. If you evaluate this polynomial at the point $(\alpha, \beta)$ you get by construction
$$\beta - \alpha^{-2}\alpha = 0$$

So $x-a \in \mathfrak{m}$.

What I did: I found a domain $R$, $x \in K \setminus R$ such that for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \leq R[x]$ there exists $a \in R$ such that $x-a \in \mathfrak{m}$. So this is a counterexample.

Comment: Oichhhh. Maybe my question is not asked sufficiently clearly. I do not demand a domain $R$ such that every maximal ideal $\frak m$ of $R[x]$ contain $x-a$, but the contrary: a ring $R$ such that there exists a maximal ideal $\frak m$ of $R[x]$ that does not contain $x-a$ for any $a \in R$. Anyway, thank you for trying to answer my question. I will vote for your answer. I will also edit my qestion to make it clearer.

Comment: This question has been reedited to correspond to the answer of Crostul. I have posted the original question in another thread.